# React Redux subscribe method being fired exponentially?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using a store.subscript() method in my React component and I noticed it gets called exponentially. My code looks like this:

```
function Alert(){
  console.log("rendering");

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const store = useStore();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(store.getState().alerts);
    if (store.getState().alerts != null) {
      setOpen(true);
      setData({ ...store.getState().alerts });
    } else {
      setData(null);
    }
  });

// ...

}
```

When I trigger a change to the store for the first time, the subscribe gets called and it prints the state to the console **one** time. The second time I trigger it, it prints 5 times, and the third time is 9 times, and so on. Is this something internal to the subscribe method? I've put logs all over my code and I none of them get triggered more than once or twice. I even put a log in the Alert component below and it only renders when the states get updated. Anyone have input? It doesn't seem to be slowing down my code at all but I'm curious what could be causing it.

Comment: The only time you should use store is when you pass it to [Provider](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider). There are react-redux hooks or the old connect function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the subscribe code to some sideEffect or lifecycle methods.
each time the execution comes into this function, a new subscription is added. thus **redux is changing once but you are listening to the change exponentially** each time. refer the code below

```
function Alert(){
  console.log("rendering");

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const store = useStore();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(()=>{
    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(store.getState().alerts);
      if (store.getState().alerts != null) {
        setOpen(true);
        setData({ ...store.getState().alerts });
      } else {
        setData(null);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  },[])

// ...

}
```